# android sudio и процессор amd

Tags: android-studio, amd

У меня компьютер с процессором amd ryzen 7 2700 и я хочу установить на свой пк android studio, но когда уже установилась пытаюсь запустить emulator выдаёт такие ошибки:Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! 
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: На AMD Android Studio умеет использовать Hypervisor Platform, встроенный в Win10. Читайте со слов "If you have an AMD processor ": https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html